# Accessing list items of a sharepoint subsite using REST oData url

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to access the items under a list in a subsite of sharepoint site collection using REST API.

To access the items of a list in a site we use: https://Server/Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items (it works)

But if I try to use the same for a subsite it doesn't work: https://Server/Site/SubSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items

Any idea on how to achieve this?

I have gone through the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx, but it doesn't give any info on subsites.
[Postman ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkgRJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get current url site `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`

Try this:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items"
```

or write url

1. http://sp
2. http://sp/sites/test
3. http://sp/sites/test/avi

Answer (score 0):

Warrior,

I tested it on my SPO environment. It could get items from a subsite.

[image]

So could you please have a check if the url is correct and the list is in the subsite? And what about the error msg?

BR

Comment: On the site and on the subsite I have created a list with the same name. I can access the site's but the subsite's cannot.These are the links I use:https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/MainSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items .   https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/MainSite/Subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items.  I use The Postman error I add it in the question